# Grouped and aligned expressions

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, braces

The effect I'm trying to achieve is illustrated here:

[image]

The blue line indicates the desired alignment axis. Specifically, I want to align the arrows but also have a curly brace to the left of the mapping expressions. I'd like to do this as simply as possible and without manual adjustment.

I've tried a number of things, mostly nesting alignment environments from `amsmath`. The obvious problem with that approach is this: by encapsulating the ‘maps-to’ expressions in their own box (to embrace them on the left), they become isolated from the outer aligning environment.

I provide this MWE to spare the reader some typing, but with the expectation that little I did is useful toward a solution.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f \colon \{\,\text{long expr}\,\} &\rightarrow B\\
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      a_1 &\mapsto b_1\\
      a_2 &\mapsto b_2
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, don't use the `minimal` class for examples. It's for testing package option loading, not for testing documents.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take that advice moving forward. I seem to remember reading somewhere, perhaps in the LaTeX SE FAQ that `minimal` and `article` are preferred. Perhaps I'm mistaken, and it wasn't `minimal`, but I'm bothered by the ghost of a recollection that there is some class specifically for these types of MWEs. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Unfortunately some sites suggest `minimal`, but they're wrong; `article` is better for minimal examples, unless the example uses specific features of another class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Bit of a cheat, but as all the lines have standard height

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f \colon \{\,\text{long expr}\,\} &\rightarrow B\\
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      a_1 \\
      a_2 
    \end{aligned}
  \right.&
    \begin{aligned}
      &\mapsto b_1\\
      &\mapsto b_2
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution produces nice spacing, and I've happily adopted it. For my own personal satisfaction, I'd love to know what a more general solution looks like, as this one appears to rely on the LHS of all `↦` being the same height as the RHS for vertical alignment.

Comment: @Timtro yes alignments (like matrices) use struts so all reasonable sized expressions have the same line height so the left can be `XXX` and the right `...` and they will align, but if you put a big nested fraction on one side you would have to use a `\vphantom` on the other side to force it to have the same height

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that uses nested `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,array,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{r@{\,}l}
f\colon\{\text{ long expr }\} & \to B \\
\left\{\begin{array}{@{}r@{}} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{array}\right. &
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}} \mapsto b_1 \\ \mapsto b_2\end{array}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution coincides with @David Carlisle's, but his use of the `aligned` environment produces better spacing than `array`. That's the only reason I accepted his over yours, but your answer is appreciated all the same.